# Dynamic validation within the model in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

Within a CREATE operation using the model validation and the "isUnique" rule, I check whether a specific value already exists in the database.

My application is a dictionary. In some cases it IS necessary to skip that validation and to allow the application to create more than one entry for one and the same word. Therefore I need a way to manipulate the validation as follows:

The validation returns an error message, as usual. In addition, there should be displayed a checkbox with a label that says something like "I confirm I want create another entry for this word" If I check the checkbox and submit the form again, then the validation should return true and the word will be stored. If the checkbox remains unchecked, the validation will continue to return false.

I thought of something like this (it's only pseudo code to illustrate what I mean. I *KNOW* that this is not working PHP code)

```
function afterValidate() {
  if ($this->validationErrors contains the observed field) {
    if ($this->data does NOT contain the extra checkbox) {
      extend $this->data with an extra checkbox;
    }
    else {
      if (extra checkbox is checked) {
        force validation to return true;
        save record;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't get it working in my model!

My first obstacle is on the second IF construct: How do I extend the data object within the model?
I can push stuff into it (my desired checkbox) and even see it, when I debug using the pr() command. But neither the Controller nor the View sees it: when I output the data object in the Controller or in the View it still contains the standard form fields but not the checkbox…?

I presume I could move the code to the Controller and get it working there, but I think it rather has to happen in the model since there is the afterValidate callback for post-processing data.

Thanks for hints!

Comment: Recommend rewriting the psuedo code in English.  As for your question, have you considered just writing custom validation methods?  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: I posted my question originally in German in another forum. Sorry, I just corrected it.

Comment: Custom validation is a thing I keep in mind. But the most important question is: how do I change the data object within the afterValidate callback?